# du of directories in a diskgroup in Oracle ASM

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-asm

In Linux, you could run the below on a directory to find the size of each sub-directory:

```
du -sh *
```

When you're in `asmcmd`in the `+FRA` disk group for example, how can I retrieve the size of each directory in the disk group in one list, instead of running `du +FRA/directory` on each and every single directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`du` of `asmcmd` doesn't support this, just put it in a loop.

```
$ dg=fra; for dir in $(asmcmd ls $dg); do echo $dg/$dir; asmcmd du $dg/$dir; done
```

Comment: That is brilliant. Have my upvote.